# retrieving results from a Resultset mysql java

Tags: java, mysql

in Java. Has anyone idea about how I can retrieve data from this query ? I can do this for simper queries, but i find this case very confusing:

```
SELECT (SELECT sum(r2.a) FROM R r2 WHERE year(r2.p) = 
'2015' and month(r2.p) < month(r1.p) ) AS Previous,
            (SELECT sum(r3.a) FROM R r3 WHERE year(r3.p) 
 = '2015' and month(r3.p) > month(r1.p) ) AS Next,
            (SELECT sum(r4.a) FROM R r4 WHERE year(r4.p) 
 = '2015' and month(r4.p) = month(r1.p) ) AS Curr
 FROM R r1
  WHERE YEAR(r1.pickupdate) = '2015';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the declared alias: `AS Curr`

```
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {
        Integer curr = rs.getInt("Curr");
        // Do something here
}
```

Comment: Happy to hear :) Please mark the correct answer for others to reuse.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement returns **boolean** aliases Previous, NextM, Cur. 
You may treat them as integer 0 or 1 like in the other answer but they are still boolean and imo that's how they should be used.

Also consider using **PreparedStatement parameters** to avoid sql injection.

```
Connection con = null; // ... assuming you already have your connection 

String sql = "SELECT ... WHERE YEAR(r1.pickupdate) = ?";

PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
try
{
    pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

    int year = 2015;
    pstmt.setInt(1, year);

    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next())
    {

        boolean previous = rs.getBoolean("Previous");
        boolean nextM = rs.getBoolean("NextM");
        boolean curr = rs.getBoolean("Curr");

        // do something here with each record
    }
} finally
{
    // release Statement resources immediately after execution
    try
    {
        pstmt.close();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
// use the same try finally approach for the connection
```